# Trouble with merging tsv files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

So I have been having an issue using pandas where it simply does not merge certain lines. For example, when trying to merge the following two excerpts together:

```
Haggai  1:1 In the second year of Darius the king, in the sixth month, in the first day of the month, the Word of Yahweh came by Haggai, the prophet, to Zerubbabel, the son of Shealtiel, governor of Judah, and to Joshua, the son of Jehozadak, the high priest, saying,
Haggai  1:2 "This is what Yahweh of Hosts says: These people say, 'The time hasn't yet come, the time for Yahweh's house to be built.'"
Haggai  1:3 Then the Word of Yahweh came by Haggai, the prophet, saying,
Haggai  1:4 "Is it a time for you yourselves to dwell in your paneled houses, while this house lies waste?
Haggai  1:5 Now therefore this is what Yahweh of Hosts says: Consider your ways.
Haggai  1:6 You have sown much, and bring in little. You eat, but you don't have enough. You drink, but you aren't filled with drink. You clothe yourselves, but no one is warm, and he who earns wages earns wages to put them into a bag with holes in it."
```

and

```
Haggai  1:1 ΕΝ τῷ δευτέρῳ ἔτει ἐπὶ Δαρίου τοῦ βασιλέως ἐν τῷ μηνὶ τῷ ἕκτῳ μιᾷ τοῦ μηνὸς ἐγένετο λόγος Κυρίου ἐν χειρὶ Ἀγγαίου τοῦ προφήτου λέγων Εἰπὸν πρὸς Ζοροβάβελ τὸν τοῦ Σαλαθιὴλ ἐκ φυλῆς Ἰούδα καὶ πρὸς Ἰησοῦν τὸν τοῦ Ἰωσεδὲκ τὸν ἱερέα τὸν μέγαν λέγων
Haggai  1:2 Τάδε λέγει Κύριος Παντοκράτωρ λέγων Ὁ λαὸς οὗτος λέγουσιν Οὐχ ἤκει ὁ καιρὸς τοῦ οἰκοδομῆσαι τὸν οἶκον Κυρίου.
Haggai  1:3 καὶ ἐγένετο λόγος Κυρίου ἐν χειρὶ Ἀγγαίου τοῦ προφήτου λέγων
Haggai  1:4 Εἰ καιρὸς μέν ὑμῖν ἐστιν τοῦ οἰκεῖν ἐν οἴκοις ὑμῶν κοιλοστάθμοις, ὁ δὲ οἶκος ὑμῶν ἐξηρήμωται;
Haggai  1:5 καὶ νῦν τάδε λέγει Κύριος Παντοκράτωρ Τάξατε δὴ τὰς καρδίας ὑμῶν εἰς τὰς ὁδοὺς ὑμῶν·
Haggai  1:6 ἐσπείρατε πολλὰ καὶ εἰσηνέγκατε ὀλίγα, ἐφάγετε καὶ οὐκ εἰς πλησμονήν, ἐπίετε καὶ οὐκ εἰς μέθην, περιεβάλεσθε καὶ οὐκ ἐθερμάνθητε ἐν αὐτοῖς, καὶ ὁ τοὺς μισθοὺς συνάγων συνήγαγεν εἰς δεσμὸν τετρυπημένον.
```

I get:

```
21  Haggai  1:1 ΕΝ τῷ δευτέρῳ ἔτει ἐπὶ Δαρίου τοῦ βασιλέως ἐν τῷ μηνὶ τῷ ἕκτῳ μιᾷ τοῦ μηνὸς ἐγένετο λόγος Κυρίου ἐν χειρὶ Ἀγγαίου τοῦ προφήτου λέγων Εἰπὸν πρὸς Ζοροβάβελ τὸν τοῦ Σαλαθιὴλ ἐκ φυλῆς Ἰούδα καὶ πρὸς Ἰησοῦν τὸν τοῦ Ἰωσεδὲκ τὸν ἱερέα τὸν μέγαν λέγων In the second year of Darius the king, in the sixth month, in the first day of the month, the Word of Yahweh came by Haggai, the prophet, to Zerubbabel, the son of Shealtiel, governor of Judah, and to Joshua, the son of Jehozadak, the high priest, saying,
22  Haggai  1:2 Τάδε λέγει Κύριος Παντοκράτωρ λέγων Ὁ λαὸς οὗτος λέγουσιν Οὐχ ἤκει ὁ καιρὸς τοῦ οἰκοδομῆσαι τὸν οἶκον Κυρίου.   This is what Yahweh of Hosts says: These people say, 'The time hasn't yet come, the time for Yahweh's house to be built.'
23  Haggai  1:3 καὶ ἐγένετο λόγος Κυρίου ἐν χειρὶ Ἀγγαίου τοῦ προφήτου λέγων    Then the Word of Yahweh came by Haggai, the prophet, saying,
24  Haggai  1:4 Εἰ καιρὸς μέν ὑμῖν ἐστιν τοῦ οἰκεῖν ἐν οἴκοις ὑμῶν κοιλοστάθμοις, ὁ δὲ οἶκος ὑμῶν ἐξηρήμωται;   "Is it a time for you yourselves to dwell in your paneled houses, while this house lies waste?
Haggai  1:5 Now therefore this is what Yahweh of Hosts says: Consider your ways.
Haggai  1:6 You have sown much, and bring in little. You eat, but you don't have enough. You drink, but you aren't filled with drink. You clothe yourselves, but no one is warm, and he who earns wages earns wages to put them into a bag with holes in it."
```

Where clearly `Haggai 1:5` and `Haggai 1:6` do not merge correctly.

The code I am using is:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_table('greekBible.txt')
df2 = pd.read_table('englishBible.txt')

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Book', 'Chapter:Verse'])

df3.to_csv('test.txt', sep="\t")
```

Keep in mind, this is only a small excerpt. Further, the two bibles are not totally aligned — there are entries in one that are not in the other and vice versa. However, this shouldn’t be a problem to my understanding.

Thank you very much for your help with this problem!

Comment: In those rows where the merge is not happening correctly is there some misalignment of the columns in the original dataframes? I tried this with the data you've supplied, and got expected results.

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik I directly copied and pasted from the original dataframes, so I don't think there is a formatting issue. However, there are fewer lines in total in the English translation than in the Greek translation, though I do not think that should be an issue!

Comment: There appears to be an issue with quotation marks in the first data snippet, is that a typo?

Comment: @AMC I am not sure I see what you are referring to. The files should be merged by the values of the first two columns, anyway. So whatever is in the third should not matter as much.

Comment: @anomicgold I was referring to the line _Haggai  1:4 "Is it a time for you yourselves to dwell in your paneled houses, while this house lies waste?_

Comment: @AMC I believe the quote is continued on the next lines. Frankly, I am not biblical expert, but I imagine this is correct.. haha

Comment: @anomicgold I'm not an expert on the bible either lol It might be an issue for the software side, though.

Comment: @AMC I think you are correct! Do you know why this is? How curious.. I will try replacing with single quotations and see if that fixes things.

Comment: @AMC I replaced all double quotations with single quotations and sure enough it seemed to work. If you want to answer, I can give it to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be missing quotes in your file, probably due to how the text was split. It is most obvious on the line *Haggai  1:4 "Is it a time for you yourselves to dwell in your paneled houses, while this house lies waste?*